# I use runtime to exchange UIImage method, but didn't run the +(void)load method, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

I create a Cocoa Touch framework and use runtime to exchange UIImage's `imageNamed`, but the framework didn't run the `+(void)load` method. I don't know why. Does anyone know the reason?

The code:

```
#import "UIImage+HCBundleImg.h"
#import <objc/message.h>

@implementation UIImage (HCBundleImg)

+ (void)load {

    Method originMethod = class_getClassMethod([self class], @selector(imageNamed:));
    Method swappedMethod = class_getClassMethod([self class], @selector(hc_imageNamed:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(originMethod, swappedMethod);
}

+ (UIImage *)hc_imageNamed:(NSString *)name {

    if (![name hasPrefix:@"HCResource.bundle/"]) {
        name = kImageBundlePath(name);
    }

    return [self hc_imageNamed:name];
}

@end
```

Comment: I think maybe I edit the xcode settings lead to this problem, It works fine when I create the `UIImage+HCBundleImg`, but not work when I modified some xcode settings(I forgot)....

Comment: Are you sure you added you `.m` file to your target and imported the `.h` file in your desired class?